# Best way to validate loadable bundle

Tags: ios

Lets say the app supports loadable bundles made by third parties. There is a protocol for a principal class so the app knows how to speak to bundles. Bundles could be downloaded from the server and dynamically added in runtime.

The problem is I need a way to validate that bundle executable doesn't harm the app. As an example I don't want bundle to be able to show UIAlertView, ever. So even if I check somehow that bundle does not support UIKit, some third parties still can show UIAlertView by trying to create it using NSClassFromString.

So the idea is to inspect the source code right before compilation and validate that it does not have keywords like UIAlertView as an example. Also it would be nice if the script is private and third party cannot just skip it.

Is there a right way to do that? Thanks

Comment: iOS license terms state: "3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. "

Comment: @MartinH thank you for your comment, what if this is not an App Store nor enterprise app, but just educational test app which works only in simulator? And another question: is this the same for Mac App?

Comment: Then it'd be ok you can do what you want. The license terms are iOS specific, I don't know what the Mac terms are. But if its only the simulator why worry about harming the app, whatever harming is anyway.

Comment: @MartinH, yeah, I thought to start simulator app, but had in mind an idea to do an App Store app. I forgot to refresh the license agreement recollection. Thank you for your answer though, if you create an answer I would mark it as the right one

Comment: Your requirement is somewhat self defeating: "how can I dynamically load code and verify that code statically"? Who says your validated bundled couldn't dynamically load more code that does what you don't want it to do?

Comment: @PatrickGoley, I wanted to find a way to validate the code statically before it is compiled into dynamic library. It was worth trying, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to release such an app to the app store because the iOS license terms state:

"3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. "

So you would be limited to a jailbroken device or enterprise app.